# Did minecraft 1.4.2 nerf high level enchantments in favour of the new Anvil?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since minecraft 1.4.2 came out yesterday, it introduced a new "Anvil" block - capable of combining enchantments from multiple items.

Last night I put two bows on the enchantment table, enchanting them both with level-30 exp. One bow gave me a sad "Power II" and the other one gave me a sad "Flame I" (I'm serious, level-30).

On the other hand, I got a "Power III & Flame I" bow with only a level-17 enchanting a few days ago in version 1.3.2. (Based on my memory; actual enchanting results or level used could be slightly off, but you see my point.)

Is this just bad luck, or has enchanting been nerfed recently?

Comment: I haven't heard anything regarding level 30 enchantments being nerfed in favor of combining via the anvil. This is just an observation from my gameplay and what I've seen/heard on the tubes

Comment: Are you sure you got Power II and not Punch II? Because if the information from Pernsteiner is correct, you can't get Power II from a level 30 enchantment. If you really did get Power II, there might be some changes in the enchanting algorithm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For fun, I figured I'd test this out. It would be understandable to nerf enchanting a little, I suppose, because of all the ways available to gain exp now. (breeding, fishing added with 1.4.2)

Fortunately, I can't seem to find anything to suggest it's been nerfed. A good googlin' gives me nothing to suggest the nerf either. Just now I received, with L26 enchants on all:

An **iron** axe got efficiency 4, unbreaking 3, fortune 2.

**Iron** sword: smite 3, looting 2.

**Iron** pickaxe: unbreaking 3. Eh.

**Iron** shovel: fortune 2, unbreaking 3.

Last night I received sharpness 3+ fire 1 on my **diamond** sword with a level 26 enchant as well.

Mojang's good with telling us these things, I think it's safe to say there's been no nerf.

Comment: Tried another level-13 enchanting on iron axe, got "Unbreaking II, Efficiency II, Fortune I". Life is good again :)

Answer (score 0):

Enchantments are just random.

Try again, test your luck. There has been no nerf.